# How to index mysql table with custom field select

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

How can i index mysql table according to given query?

```
  SELECT 
      IF(
        flag IN ('A', 'B') 
        AND status IN ('on'),
        'A',
        flag
      ) AS customized_flag,
      IF(
        agent_group = 'A',
        'group_1',
        'group_2'
      ) AS group,
      COUNT(*) AS total 
    FROM
      mytable
    WHERE type IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
      AND publish = 1 
      AND status IN ('on', 'deleted', 'expired',) 
    GROUP BY customized_flag,
      agency_package_status ;
```

flag can be A,B,C,D

agent_group can be A,B,C,D

type is any integer number

My sample table data is shown below

[image]

Comment: Your query is invalid because the `group` if expression is not an aggregate but you are using `GROUP BY`.  Off the top of my head, add indices to the columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
GROUP BY customized_flag, `group`
```

Add

```
INDEX(publish, type, status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Query is valid Questioner is trying to find out the way to add index on custom field in this query customized_flag that is not exists as field in table... but in query he created to get required result ...